# When I return or when I'm returning?

Tags: grammar, tense

Should I say "When I return from vacation, I ..." or "When I'm returning from vacation, I..." if I want to emphasize that the act of returning (and what follows) is something that happens regularly (e.g. every year)?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you gave us the actual (rest of the) sentence as well, and a bit of context which you would like to put it in.

Answer (score -1):

**When I return from vacation** should be fine.

**When I'm returning** sounds a bit odd.